# MySQL pagination on complex multi table queries

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, wordpress

Currently I'm running a MySQL query like this

```
$query = "
        SELECT 
        t1.id AS 'post_id',
        t1.post_title AS 'post_title',
        t1.post_status AS 'post_status',
        COUNT( t1.id ) AS 'row_count', //this one is not working
        COUNT( t2.tag_id ) AS 'link_count',
        GROUP_CONCAT( t2.tag_id) AS 'link_id',
        GROUP_CONCAT( t2.url) AS 'url',
        GROUP_CONCAT( t2.title) AS 'title',
        GROUP_CONCAT( t2.active) AS 'active',
        FROM $posts_table AS t1
        JOIN $tags_table AS t2 ON ( t1.id = t2.post_id )
        GROUP BY t1.id
        ORDER BY t1.id DESC
        LIMIT $start_from, $row_to_show;
    ";
```

Every part of this query is executing well except `COUNT( t1.id ) AS 'row_count',` line.

I want to count total numbers of rows found in **t1 table** but when I'm dumping the array

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
var_dump($result->row_count);
```

It is giving me `NULL`.

If I use it inside a loop

```
foreach ( $result as $result ){
    echo $result->row_count;
}
```

Then the value is same as `link_count` that is declared in the very next line `COUNT( t2.link_id ) AS 'link_count',` gives the value I want.

Please give me some idea about how I can use pagination (like 10 out of 30 results) on this query.

Comment: Check if you have included  global $wpdb;

Comment: Yes there is no problem with `$wpdb`, the query is working fine except the line I mentioned above. I must be doing something wrong and can't find out what that is.. :(

Comment: t1.id AS 'post_id', and now you are again referring as t1.id make it post_id and let me know :)

Comment: I changed it but no luck yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many but didn't succeed so I made another separate DB query for just pagination.

```
$page_query = "
    SELECT p.id 
    FROM 
    $posts_table as p, 
    $tag_table as c
    WHERE p.id=c.post_id
    GROUP BY p.id
";
```

it gives me the result of total numbers of rows that I can use for pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with GROUP BY.

Try this query:

```
$query = "
        SELECT 
        t1.id AS 'post_id',
        t1.post_title AS 'post_title',
        t1.post_status AS 'post_status',
        COUNT( t1.id ) AS 'row_count', 
        COUNT( t2.tag_id ) AS 'link_count',
        GROUP_CONCAT( t2.tag_id) AS 'link_id',
        GROUP_CONCAT( t2.url) AS 'url',
        GROUP_CONCAT( t2.title) AS 'title',
        GROUP_CONCAT( t2.active) AS 'active',
        FROM $posts_table AS t1, $tags_table AS t2 
        GROUP BY t1.id 
        HAVING t1.id = t2.post_id 
        ORDER BY t1.id DESC
        LIMIT $start_from, $row_to_show;
    ";
```

Answer (score 0):

a quesy like `COUNT( DISTINCT X ) .. GROUP BY X` will always result in the value 1, and if you skip DISTINCT you get the number of combined joins

there is ways to fetch the count in mysql, but its alot easier to just use `mysql_num_rows()` or `count()` in php.

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

foreach($results as $result)
{
    $result->row_count =  count($results);
    ...
}
```

above only show the number of fetched rows,
if you want the total you need to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `mysql_num_rows()`

```
$query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ...
```

and

```
$result_count = mysql_num_rows();
```

Comment: I know it is a kind of stupid question but can you please give me an example/syntax of how I can use it with `$wpdb`